# How to customise a Mybatis generator file for multiple users?

Tags: xml, mybatis

Is it possible to create a Mybatis generator file which handles differences in the project path for many users when the file is shared in a team? For example

```
   <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="com.x.y.mybatis.mapper"  targetProject="MYDIR/src/java">
```

So "MYDIR" varies between users. In fact some are working on Windows, and some on Linux, so the path format can differ. There are several project path elements sprinkled throughout the generator file.

Seems like I need a way of referencing environment variables or system properties within the XML, but I'm not aware of any way of doing this with Mybatis.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. In your generator file, simply add the following -

```
<generatorConfiguration>

    <properties resource="mybatisGenProps.properties"></properties>
```

and in the mybatisGenProps.properties file add something like this

```
PROJECT=myProjDir
```

Then you can reference the property like this -

```
   <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="com.x.y.mybatis.mapper"  targetProject="${PROJECT}/src/java">
```